# Summing over rows of a matrix in Matlab with the same index

Tags: arrays, matrix, matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `hxk` where element `ik` reports an index from `{1,2,...,s<=h}`. The indices can be repeated across rows. I want to obtain `B` of dimension `sx(k-1)` where element `j` is the sum of the rows of `A(:,1:k-1)` with index `j`. For example if

```
A = [0.4  5    6    0.3  1;
     0.6 -0.7  3    2    2;
     0.3  4.5  6    8.9  1;
     0.9  0.8  0.7  3    3;
     0.7  0.8  0.9  0.5  2]
```

the result shoud be

```
B = [0.7  9.5  12   9.2;
     1.3  0.1  3.9  2.5;
     0.9  0.8  0.7  3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a multi-column version of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  Failing that, you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) as follows:

```
[m n] = size(A);
rows = ceil(1/(n-1):1/(n-1):m);
cols = repmat(1:n-1,1,m);
B = full(sparse(A(rows,end), cols, A(:,1:end-1).'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) sum(A(A(:,end)==x,1:end-1),1), unique(A(:,end)), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

The key point is selecting rows `A(A(:,end)==x,1:end-1)` where `x` is a unique element of `A(:,end)`